# Determine the varying area of the shaded region

Tags: geometry, area

How to estimate the area of the shaded region shown in the attached Figure?

[image: Figure]

Note that in the figure, $p$ has a maximum and minimum values of $p_a$ and $p_b$ respectively. Moreover, $p$ follows a Gaussian distribution function of the form:

$$ 
p =  \frac{\alpha}{\beta \sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(\theta-\pi)^{2}}{2\beta^{2}}}+p_a
$$

Yet another limitation is $p_a$ could be greater than the radius of the outer circle (i.e. $p_a > D/2$). I tried the following approach:

$$ 
A =  2 \int_0^\pi p\ R\ d\theta
$$

However, I feel the solution is valid only if $p_a$ < $R$ (i.e. the radius of the circle). Am I right? If yes, how to approach if $p_a$ > $R$. Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the "double integral" approach you used?

Comment: @Jared I tried using int(_p_ _R_ d _theta_, 0, 2 pi). _R_ is the radius of the circle. Not sure how to proceed further

Comment: @Jared Added the details of my approach. Can you/someone help me?

Comment: I have now switched four times between the question and the figure. It is absolutely unclear what you are up to. There is no $p$ to be seen in the figure. I see two nonconcentric circles. The  shaded area is of course equal to the difference of the disk areas, etc.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks for your efforts to help and sorry for the inconvenience. $p$ is a function that describes the variation in thickness of the shaded area as a function of theta. Further, the outer geometry is a concentric circle whereas the inner curve follows a Gaussian distribution $p$. Accepting your answer that the shaded area is equal to difference in disk areas, can you suggest me how to evaluate the area of the shaded region based on the Gaussian function $p$, specifically when $p_a$ > $R$.

Comment: There is a problem with your formula for $p$: it should give $p(0)=p_a$ and $p(\pi)=p_b$, but that is not the case.

Comment: @Stoka Why don't you call the coefficient as $A$ or the like? Is your figure computer drawn to scale and using some constants? If $ p_a > R$ are you making a curve on the outside of circle of radius $R=D/2?$

Comment: @Aretino Thanks for your interest to provide an answer.  In this question $p_b$ is the estimate of $p$ at $ \theta = \pi$.  Considering this clarification, will it be possible for you to provide some hint to my question.

Comment: @Narasimham To clarify your points (1) the figure is drawn using MS Word and (2) over time the inner curve would shrink in such a way that both $p_a$ and $p_b$ will be inside the circle with $p_a > D/2 $

Comment: There is some confusion in your question. Do you realize that, as given by your formula, $p(0)$ cannot be equal to $p_a$? From the same formula it follows that if $p_a>R$ then $p(\theta)>R$ for every $\theta$, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive.

Comment: @Aretino Thanks for your insights. I am well aware that $p(0) \approx p_a$ (not exactly but very close) for the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ I am working with. I am more interested in obtaining the area of the annulus when $p_a > R$

Comment: If $p_a>R$ and $\alpha/\beta>0$, then $p(\theta)>0$ and the result in my answer applies.

Answer (score 1):

If $p(\theta)$ is the annulus thickness as a function of the angle, symmetric around $\theta=0$, then the annulus area is given by:
$$
area=2\int_0^{\pi}\int_{R-p(\theta)}^R r\,dr\,d\theta=
2\int_0^{\pi} \left(Rp(\theta)-{1\over2}p^2(\theta)\right)\,d\theta,
$$
but that doesn't work (of course) for $p(\theta)>R$, because a negative radial coordinate is a nonsense.

EDIT.

But if $p(\theta)>R$ for every $\theta$ then of course:

$$
area=2\int_0^{\pi}\int_{R}^{p(\theta)-R} r\,dr\,d\theta=
2\int_0^{\pi} \left({1\over2}p^2(\theta)-Rp(\theta)\right)\,d\theta.
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your time and attempt. I am more interested in the solution for the area when $p(\theta) > R$.

Comment: What is the meaning of the area if $p(\theta)>R$? That makes sense only if $p(\theta)>R$ for every $\theta$, and in that case you can make the obvious changes in the above formula.

Comment: See my edited answer. I presume you can compute the integrals by yourself: just be warned that if $p=ae^{-b\theta^2}$ (as you seem to imply), the integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the confusion, I meant $p_a > R$ not $p(\theta)>R$.

Comment: From the expression you provide for $p$, it follows that $p(\theta)>R$ if $p_a>R$. Unless of course $\alpha$ or $\beta$ are negative (see also my comment at your question).